# Entire module is not detected by __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I have a relatively small python program which is setup like this

```
Root
  --Network
    --DTO
      Lots of py files which contain classes.
  Other py files in the project
```

Both in the Network and the DTO folder there is an empty `__init__.py`.

When I do `from Network import DTO`, `import Network`, `Import Network.DTO` I cannot use the module at all. The debugger says it's completely empty. The root contains the py file I am actually executing.

Both the the `__init__.py` files in the Network and DTO folder are compiled to `pyc` while all actual python files aren't.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am using python 2.7

Comment: Have you tried `from Network.DTO import *` and see if anything is available that way? If often helps to print out `sys.path` inside the py file you are actually executing after doing the imports.

Comment: @JacobIRR Nope that also doesn't work :(. Sys.path in both _init__.py contain the path of my root folder.

Comment: If you're running Python from a directory other than `Root`, you won't be able to import anything from the `Network` module.

Comment: @ZachGates I am not running python from a different directory then the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need to import the submodules in your `__init__.py`. It becomes more difficult to add an import for every submodule if you have many, as you do. In the case of many submodules (and in general), use `__all__`.

Here's an example for `Root/Network/DTO/__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = [
    'sample_module',
    ...
]

for module in __all__:
    __import__('DTO.%s' % module)
```

Now you can do `from Network.DTO import sample_module`. The same idea holds for your other modules, as well.

Comment: So you can't have sub folders without having to a huge amount of bookkeeping in the __init__.py files? I thought that should just import everything in a folder if they are empty.

Comment: `__all__` marks the modules that are "public" in the module. So a submodule that is only for use within the project wouldn't be included. Any module file can also have an `__all__` to include the "public" classes/functions/variables of that module. i.e. in `sample_module`, I might have the classes `Foo` and `Bar`, resulting in `__all__ = [Foo, Bar]`.