# Call functions in a sub sub module in python2

Tags: python, keras, python-module

This is legal in Python3.

```
import keras
keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(...)
```

But I have to change it to this for it to work in Python2.

```
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
sequence.pad_sequences(...)
```

Is there something wrong with Keras or is this a new feature in Python3?

This question has not been asked before to my best knowledge. Sorry if this is a dumb question but I don't really know what key words I should use to search for this...

Comment: This is not my experience when using Keras. In Python 2 your first example works as expected, and in the source, while Keras does not define `__all__` it does explicitly import it's submodules explicitly - which is the other mechanism outlined in the documentation @ZachGates linked to. What version of keras are you using (I'm on 2.0.8) - perhaps an older version does not do the explicit imports in `__init__`?

Comment: I was using 2.0.2 but it seems the `__init__.py` hasn't been changed since then. [Here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blame/master/keras/__init__.py#L10)

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Also is there a folder in your working directory called keras?

Comment: Yes exactly! My folder is named keras. That's why I'm having this problem. Thank you and sorry for the delayed response!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that depends on the module. If the submodule's name is included in `__all__` in the module's `__init__.py`, you'll be able to access it in the way you expect. You can see how `__all__` works in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45774712/3496038). Or read [the documentation on packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `import` statement uses the following convention: if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered. It is up to the package author to keep this list up-to-date when a new version of the package is released. Package authors may also decide not to support it, if they don’t see a use for importing * from their package.

In the case of `keras`, it seems that the module's `__init__.py` either:

- does not define `__all__`
- does not include `preprocessing` in `__all__`

Comment: But why is this different in 2 and 3?